# making a function affect only 'this' object in onclick=function(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want making a function affect only 'this' object!

but it worked in previous clicked object also..

What should I do??

It shown at this ▼

```js
function toggle(obj, className) {
  obj.classList.toggle(className);
  $('.box').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    obj.classList.toggle(className);

  })
}
```

```css
.btn-toggle.on {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.box.on {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button class="btn-toggle" onclick="toggle(this,'on')">toggle</button>
<button class="btn-toggle" onclick="toggle(this,'on')">toggle</button>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to post your code. Please see [ask] and provide a [mcve] in order to help us to help you.

Comment: `$(obj).on('click',function(e){})` is what you are looking for. You can also use jQuery for toggling classes. `$(obj).toggleClass(className)`

Comment: I try that. but I want to apply that only one object T.T.. I update my case additionally

Comment: I don't get what you are saying.

Comment: I think you want something like this `$(function() {
  $('.btn-toggle').on('click', function() {
    $(this).nextAll('.box').first().toggleClass('on');
  });
});` This code finds the next `.box` element and toggle the class on that. remove the inline on click for this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to unbind previously added click event please check the code below:

```js
function toggle(obj, className) {
$('.box').off( "click");//Unbind previously added event
  obj.classList.toggle(className);
  $('.box').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    obj.classList.toggle(className);

  })
}
```

```css
.btn-toggle.on {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.box.on {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button class="btn-toggle" onclick="toggle(this,'on')">toggle</button>
<button class="btn-toggle" onclick="toggle(this,'on')">toggle</button>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Great if it works please mark answer as correct and upvote